# A module has been installed and Python is able to import it in the dist-packages folder but not anywhere else

Tags: python, harvest

I am working on harvest API for Python. When I run Python on terminal in 
`/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`.

It is able to import harvest. But when I run the same command in any other folder it isn't able to recognize the same and throws `ImportError`.

The module I am using is in (got this from `inspect.getfile`).

`'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_harvest_redux-3.1.1-py2.7.egg/harvest/harvest.pyc'`

How can I go about this?

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: using `sudo pip`

Comment: i think the problem is in python path. what should the correct pythonpath